# fill-paragraph chokes on semicolons

Tags: fill-paragraph

I use `mutt` for email (outside of emacs) and set my `EDITOR` to an `emacsclient` invocation. Thus, `mutt` spawns `emacsclient` in the same terminal when I want to compose an E-mail, then catches the output file when I quit.

This buffer operates in `Fundamental Server` mode. Most things are satisfactory; however, when I use `fill-paragraph` on a paragraph with a semicolon in it (used as in ordinary English), it interprets the semicolon for some reason and fills badly. Thus:

```
This is a sentence containing enough text to overflow the fill-column; when I try to fill, it fails.
```

With `fill-column` at 80, this should fill to:

```
This is a sentence containing enough text to overflow the fill-column; when I
try to fill, it fails.
```

Instead, it becomes:

```
This is a sentence containing enough text to overflow the fill-column; when I
                                                                     ; try to
                                                                     ; fill, it
                                                                     ; fails.
```

This is obviously not very useful. The same behavior occurs in `text-mode`. I assume emacs is parsing the semicolon as a comment delimiter, or something of that nature; however, it's unclear to me why this should occur in either `fundamental-mode` or `text-mode`, which shouldn't accomodate specific programming languages.

How do I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: Could you try with `emacs -Q`? I opened `emacs -Q`, set `fill-column` to 80, did `M-x fundamental-mode`, yanked your sample text, with point at the end pressed `M-q`. It worked as expected. Same with `text-mode`.

Comment: Okay, with `-Q` it works correctly. This would point to a problem with my init files?

Comment: I think so. You should check to what `M-q` is bound in your config, or try calling `M-x fill-paragraph` explicitly to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Explicitly running `fill-paragraph` still has the same issue. On a quick glance, nothing in my `.emacs` should be relevant to `fill-paragraph`, but I may be missing something. What sort of things influence its functionality?

Comment: Well, it all depends from your config actually. You should bisect it, commenting out piece by piece to track down what is causing the problem. Especially since it is working fine with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: So when I start up a completely new emacs, the behavior also vanishes. It seems that something strange happened in my long-running server session that caused this; killing it and starting a new one fixes it as well. Can I self-close this somehow?

Comment: What is the file extension of the file you are editing?

Comment: @TomHunt I suppose so. It would be helpful to rest of the community if you could provide a solution, maybe by answering your own question with what you did. But I think we need a moderator here, I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: I would love to provide a solution, but what I actually did was "restart the emacs session once", and now it's fixed and I can't reproduce.

Comment: To comment on a very old question: I had the same problem, and I think the reason was that emacs was in "Recursive editing mode", indicated by square brackets around the parentheses showing the major and minor modes. Exiting the recursive editing mode by `C-M-c` solved the problem.